# Chrome App File System. Can't write local file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to write a local file within  a Chrome App.

The issue is I can't get pass the fileEntry.createWriter call. When I debug, everything stops there and no error shows up in the console.

```
 chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile', suggestedName: 'myfile.html'}, function(fileEntry) {
     fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log('Write completed.');
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
      };
      fileWriter.write(new Blob([document.getElementById("HTMLFile").value], {type: 'text/plain'})); 
     }, errorHandler);
  });
```

Chrome Ver: Version 40.0.2214.28 beta (64-bit)
OS: OS X 10.10.1

Comment: Use console.log to display some intermediate values, such as the values passed to the chooseEntry and createWriter callbacks. This will no doubt tell you what's wrong. If you want more help, post a small, complete app here, including the manifest.json file.

Comment: To amplify Marc's comment, there are a bunch of troubling ambiguities in this question. There is no such thing as a "Chrome Web App," and the term "Packaged App" is obsolete. These terminology errors make the manifest and event-page files, as well as the event-page error log, all the more essential for answering this question, as it's very likely you're actually not building a Chrome App, or else that your error is staring you in face in the event-page console.

Comment: "Packaged App" is obsolete? Not according to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo

Comment: OK I did change the title to Chrome App.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. You need to define the errorHandler argument on  the fileEntry.createWriter() call. I also think you need to put the MIME type of the file to text/html.

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile', suggestedName:'myfile.html'}, function(fileEntry) {
     fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
       fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
         console.log('Write completed.');
       };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
      };
      fileWriter.write(new Blob([document.getElementById("HTMLFile").value], {type: 'text/html'})); 
     }, function(){console.warn("Your error message here");});
  });
```